# WPF Canvas Only Extends to the Right?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, canvas, transform

I'm making a WPF application using C# and I am in the stage of developing more UI for it. I have all my components such as TextBlocks and other Canvases inside of a main Canvas, but if I drag the left side of it to make more room, it expands on the right side, meaning I have to move everything over. The same thing happens when I try and extend the top; The bottom gets bigger. I have the RenderTransformOrigin of the Canvas set to 0,0 so I'm not quite sure what is going on. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: What's probably happening is that you are just increasing the width/height of the canvas. A canvas positions everything internally relative to its top-left corner. Resizing the canvas isn't going to reposition everything inside it.

Comment: @Abion47 That does sound like a feasible explanation. Is there a way I can move where the canvas positions everything relative to?

Comment: Why do you have main Canvas at all? There are much more capable Panels for the layout of an application, like StackPanel, WrapPanel, Grid, etc.

Answer (score 0):

By default, a Canvas doesn't have a Width or Height, its actual size depends if you set those properties explicitly, or if you set HorizontalAlignment or VerticalAlignment to `Stretch`.

In either case, elements inside of a Canvas are aligned relative to its top-left corner, except if you explicitly set their `Canvas.Top`, `Canvas.Left`, `Canvas.Right` and/or `Canvas.Bottom` properties.

You could also position elements containing a Geometry (like derivatives of `Shape`, Path being a common example) by their absolute Geometry coordinates. Actually this already is the way they are rendered.

Regarding your comment in the question, usually you don't change where things align relative to the Canvas, since it is much easier (I think even *recommended*) to reposition the canvas itself, so that everything it contains would be repositioned too.

Common ways to do that would be adding elements to a Canvas, and then position that Canvas inside another "parent" Canvas, similar to "grouping" in vector design programs like CorelDraw/Inkscape/Illustrator.

Another way would be to use `RenderTransform` property of Canvas containing the elements you want to reposition.

After you get used to see Canvas as a "coordinate system", you can and should think of Canvas-inside-Canvas-inside-Canvas-... as a way of hierarchically grouping things that share the same cartesian space, as opposed to Panels and ContentControls, which are nested inside one another and cannot typically share space.

Answer (score 0):

Like I said in my comment, all the controls inside the canvas are positioned relative to the canvas' top left point. If you want them to retain their "position" when the canvas is resized to the left or top, you will need to offset them yourself. You could do this with a utility method that you call whenever you want to resize the canvas:

```
public static void StretchWidthLeft(Canvas canvas, double newWidth)
{
    double diff = newWidth - canvas.Width;
    canvas.Width = newWidth;

    foreach (UIElement child in canvas.Children)
    {
        Canvas.SetLeft(child, Canvas.GetLeft(child) + diff);
    }
}

public static void StretchHeightTop(Canvas canvas, double newHeight)
{
    double diff = newHeight - canvas.Height;
    canvas.Height = newHeight;

    foreach (UIElement child in canvas.Children)
    {
        Canvas.SetTop(child, Canvas.GetTop(child) + diff);
    }
}
```

Note that these methods do not reposition the canvases themselves. How you would do that depends on how the canvas' parent is maintaining their position.